# Error when using cv::addWeighted

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, runtime-error

I was walking through an example, and got an error on the following line after running the code

```
cv::addWeighted(temp_image, 1.0, noise_image, 1.0, 0.0, temp_image);
```

This is the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   cv::Exception:
>   /Users/abd/Documents/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1987:
>   error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays
>   have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op
>   scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

This is the error. How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you show us some more code we can try give more details, otherwise @Barriel answer is ok. Note also that `addWieighted` with `alpha = 1`, `beta = 1` and `gamma = 0` is just the sum of the two images: `temp_image += noise_image;`. Anyhow, pay attention to saturation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `temp_image` and `noise_image` have the same **size** and **channel number**. Usually, it happens when one of the images is `BGR` and the other is `GRAY`.